# onmouseover/out задержка смены изображений

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="image" href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="img/telephone.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='img/telephone-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/telephone.png'">
</a>
```

Пример кода еще сырой. Буду переделывать на jQuery. В данном случае происходит резкая смена изображений. Возможно ли как-то создать задержку смены при наведении, как с hover и transition?

Comment: Если нужна задержка - то это вам `setTimeout` нужен. Но лучше все-таки сначала перейти на jquery, потому что в одну строку такое писать будет неудобно.

Answer (score 0):

Чем тут поможет jquery
Чтоб анимировать смену изображений лучше использовать два img

```js
document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('click', _=>{
  document.querySelector('.img01').classList.toggle('hide')
  document.querySelector('.img02').classList.toggle('hide')
})
```

```css
.image{
position: relative;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
img.hide{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
    <a href="#" class="image">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/tech" alt="" class="img01">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people" alt="" class="img02 hide">
    </a>
```

Вариаций данного кода много
Вариация с таймеромЖ

```js
let timer
let time = 300
document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseenter', _=>{

  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(toggle, time)
})
document.querySelector('.image').addEventListener('mouseleave', _=>{

  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(toggle, time)
})
function toggle(){
  document.querySelector('.img01').classList.toggle('hide')
  document.querySelector('.img02').classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

```css
.image{
position: relative;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
img.hide{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="image">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/tech" alt="" class="img01">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/people" alt="" class="img02 hide">
    </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Кажется ответ на ваш вопрос вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535217/jquery-transit-mouseover (там есть пример)

> You create a queue of animations. Remove that queue with the stop()
>   function.
>
> $("#A").mouseover( function() { $("#A").stop().transition({ opacity:
>   '0'}, 500);}); }); $(function() { $("#A").mouseout(  function(){
>   $("#A").stop().transition({ opacity: '1'}, 500);}); });